# Is there a way to get columns names of dataframe in pyspark without reading the whole dataset?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I have huges datasets in my HDFS environnement, say 500+ datasets and all of them are around 100M+ rows. I want to get only the column names of each dataset without reading the whole datasets because it will take too long time to do that. My data are `json` formatted and I'm reading them using the classic spark json reader : `spark.read.json('path')`. So what's the best way to get columns names without wasting my time and memory ?

Thanks...

Comment: `spark.read.json('path').columns` might do the trick, but could involve scanning through the data to infer the schema

Comment: @mck yes it does the job, but still read the whole dataset before returning the column names !

Answer (score 0):

from the official doc :

> If the schema parameter is not specified, this function goes through the input once to determine the input schema.

Therefore, you cannot get the column names with only the first line.
Still, you can do an extra step first, that will extract one line and create a dataframe from it, then extract the column names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Steven. Could you give me maybe a code snippet to do this first step you're mentionning ? I'm beginner to pyspark.

Comment: @BoubacarTraoré That's not a pyspark step. You have to do that using local commands (something like `hdfs dfs` or linux commands). Then you read with pyspark.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Steven. However, I found a solution in pure `pyspark` ^-^

Answer (score 0):

One answer could be the following :

1. Read the data using `spark.read.txt('path')` method
2. Limit the number of rows to 1 with the method `limit(1)` since we just want the header as column names
3. Convert the table to `rdd` and collect it as a list with the method `collect()`
4. Convert the first row collected from `unicode string` to python `dict` (since I'm working with `json` formatted data).
5. The keys of the above dict is exactly what we are looking for (columns names as `list` in python).

This code worked for me:

```
from ast import literal_eval

literal_eval(spark.read.text('path').limit(1)
                                    .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
                                    .collect()[0]).keys()
```

The reason it works faster might be that `pyspark` won't load the whole dataset with all the field structures if you read it using `txt` format (because everything is read as a big string), it's lighter and more efficient for that specific case.